# How to apply media queries on span-text on top of parallax-background?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a Bootstrap 3 website with a parallax-background (stellar.js).

I am trying to create a centered text on top of this background within span-tags, which should change its size responsively according to the screen size. As the ".background-photo span" is using a fixed width of 1280px, I am intending to apply media queries on the width to change the size accordingly on smaller resolutions.

The problem is that my media queries are not working between screen-widths of 767 and 1223px and the text is breaking out of the span. The text box should stay centered and responsively change its size without breaking the respective row-width.

Please have a look at the JS BIN I created and change the window size to see the problem:

[JS BIN Example](http://jsbin.com/UjIpati/2/)

I would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS finally solved my problem: [final JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/UjIpati/8/)

```
    .background-photo span {

    bottom: 100px;

    background-color: black;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    color: white;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -640px;
    font-size: 38px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 black, 0 0 10px black;
    width: 1280px;
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .background-photo span {

    margin-left: -150px;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 300px;

  }
}


@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .background-photo span {

    margin-left: -225px;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 450px;

  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .background-photo span {


    margin-left: -300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 600px;

  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .background-photo span {

    margin-left: -450px;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 900px;  

  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .background-photo span {

  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #service-container {
    width: auto;  

  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your .container div and its parent  are not adjusting their widths together at certain breakpoints. At one point, media queries adjust the parent span to have a width of 400px, while the .container div does not also reduce to 400px.

I would suggest reconfiguring your bootstrap media queries to make sure both of those elements are changing widths at the same breakpoints. If you can, give the parent span an id so it can be easily accessed.

Comment: Perhaps their suggestions were valid for a similar installation but it seems pretty clear to me that simply adding an extra css property here and there within the problem query thresholds should do the trick - unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I did not touch Bootstrap's generic media queries [link] (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).These are unfortunately written in LESS. For the span-text  I used the media queries that were recommended by CSS-Tricks [link] (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).  Is there a CSS version of the generic Bootstrap 3 media queries?

Comment: Using inspect element I am able to see the media queries that are affecting the .container div are located in boostrap.css and begin on line 811. There are only 3 thresholds for this element, whereas there are many more for the `.background-photo span` element. If you link to a custom stylesheet in your html `<head>` you should be able to override those media queries for .container (provided your custom stylesheet is linked below the reference to bootstrap.css). Alternatively, you could add those css rules to your JSBin window and include `!important` tags